# set turtle-only variable as patch coordinates

Tags: coordinates, netlogo

I'm creating a simulation where shoplifters target a store (lime patch) and make a decision whether or not to shoplift there.

- Some shoplifters "`professionals`" target the most vulnerable store in a radius
- "`novice`" shoplifters make a decision to shoplift or not once they arrive at their closest store.
- Once over a lime patch `turtles` will make a decision to shoplift; if perception of risk is 60 or below and they haven't been deterred by being apprehended previously.

  - 98% of shoplifts are successful as they are not detected by store security,
  - 5% of the detected are successfully deterred and the attempt is not successful,
  - 99% of the 95% shoplifters who were detected and not deterred are apprehended by security before let go and
  - 97% of non-professional shoplifters are deterred from shoplifting again finally
  - the remaining 1% escaped security and successfully shoplifted.

The piece of code I am struggling with is

```
set apprehended-here apprehended-here pxcor pycor of patch-here
```

which doesn't work. I am trying to set a turtle-own variable as the coordinates of the store/s where they have been apprehended so I can inform a later decision

*(If a shoplifter has been apprehended at this store previously there will be police involvement).*

Am I going the right way about informing this?

```
ask shoplifters [ if [pcolor] of patch-here = lime  and                       
perception-of-risk <= 60 and forever-deterred = 0          

[ifelse (random-float 1 < 0.98)  [                            
  set successful-shoplifts successful-shoplifts + 1 ]         

  [ifelse (random-float 1 < 0.05) [                            
    set successful-shoplifts successful-shoplifts + 0 ]        

    [ifelse (random-float 1 < 0.99 ) [                       
      set security-apprehension security-apprehension + 1 
      if professional = 0 and (random-float 1 < 0.97) [set forever-deterred 1]    
      set apprehended-here apprehended-here pxcor pycor of patch-here
      ]
      [set successful-shoplifts successful-shoplifts + 1 ]       

  ]]]]
end
```

Comment: Chad- if Jen's answer below has sorted out your issue, please click the little check mark near the top left of the answer to mark it as accepted and to indicate that this question has been resolved.

Comment: Thank you for informing me of this feature @Luke C!

Comment: No problem! It often gets missed, I don't think it's very obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of this is a conceptual problem and part is a code problem. The conceptual problem is this - are you expecting the shoplifter to keep track of all the patches where it has been apprehended? If so, then the shoplifter needs to keep track of multiple patches. Or is it just the most recent location where apprehended? I think you want all the locations.

In this case, the best way to store the locations is as a `patch-set` (look this up in the NetLogo Dictionary) of the locations. So you want to add the new patch to the existing patch-set. Try this:

```
set apprehended-here (patch-set apprehended-here patch-here)
```

To make this work, you will need to assign an empty patch-set when the shoplifter is first created. You will also need the code to work out whether a patch is in a patch-set when the shoplifter is apprehended. That will be something like:

```
if member? patch-here apprehended-here [ < punish > ]
```